# Many to many relations in Domain Driven Design

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregate, relationships

I am new at domain driven design, and want to learn some about aggregates. For example I have a `User` and `Role` entities.

```
public class User {
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public string Username {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<Role> Roles {get; set;}
}

public class Role {
   public string Id{get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

In this stuation, User is an aggregate root. Roles are part of user. But If I want to use Many-to-many relations with Role and User, how changes the aggregation? In this stuation which is the aggregate root?

Comment: It doesn't; it's still an aggregate root.  Keep in mind that DDD is fundamentally a *design* technique, not a coding technique.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just because you have a many to many relationship at a data or database level, doesn't mean it has to be represented in code. You should model for the relationships you care about or are useful to you. The relationship of roles to users is more of an implementation detail and not something worth modelling at all at a code level, let the database handle the consistency. Knowing all the users in a role seems like more of a user search capability than anything useful in working with a role.

In either case you really don't want to model both directions of a many to many case in code at the same time, because you will run into circular reference and consistency issues. Databases are designed to handle that consistency gracefully, let them do the hard work and only model the relationship in one direction at a time in code. Chances are your users are really only interested in one direction of such relationships at a time anyway.

Comment: plus1. From hard won experience, do not mix your domain (business) model with the relational data design. First you want to keep these things decoupled and second,  a relational DB engine will be warp factors faster than mere code.

Answer (score 2):

> In this stuation, User is an aggregate root. Roles are part of user. But If I want to use Many-to-many relations with Role and User, how changes the aggregation? In this stuation which is the aggregate root?

Aggregates don't share *entities*.

Which means, if "Role" is a thing that changes over time, then each instance of role will belong to one and only one aggregate.

If role entities aren't shared, then having them as part of the same aggregate as the user entity is fine.

If role entities are shared, then what normally happens is identifier values are used to describe the relationships.  In other words, the join table gets a representation in your domain model.

Depending on your design, it could make sense for the join table to belong to `User` or to role.  It could also be that the join table is an aggregate of its own (the relationship between user and role being a thing that has a life cycle of its own, possibly with its own rules).

Comment: I would add that if the role entities are shared, they become aggregate roots themselves, and the other entities only need ID references to them. In my experience, there is generally no need to represent the join table in the domain model. I like that to keep that strictly in the infrastructure layer. It is only used to produce results. For example, it allows me to query one entity based on properties of the other: "Give me all Users with a Role named 'Admin'." The result is simply a set of Users, who merely have references to Role IDs. The domain need not know they came from a join table.